# Showing the next Billing Cycle Start Date correctly in SQL - [Should show the future billing date according to the report run date]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SSRS report where i shows 'next Billing Cycle' StartDate as a column. This report runs against the report generated date and shows the next billing cycle date.

For Eg.,

If my Billing Start Date is '02 MAR 2018' and My Billing Cycle Frequency is '3 Months'. If I run the report on '05 MAR 2018' then I want to show 'JUN 03 2018' AS next Billing Start Date. And if I run the report on 'JUN 05 2018' then I want to show '03 SEP 2018' AS next billing Start Date and so on..

Currently am using the below logic.,

```
DECLARE @ReportRundDate    DATETIME = '2019-09-01', 
        @Billingdate     DATETIME = '2019-07-01', 
        @BillingCycle INT = 3 

       SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Dateadd(month, (Ceiling((Cast(Datediff(month, @Billingdate, @ReportRundDate)AS DECIMAL(18, 3))/@BillingCycle) ) + 
       (
       CASE WHEN Datepart (day, @ReportRundDate) > Datepart(day, @Billingdate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * @BillingCycle, @Billingdate), 103) 
       + ' - ' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Dateadd(month, @BillingCycle, Dateadd(month, ( Ceiling (Datediff(month, @billingdate, @ReportRundDate)*1.0 / @BillingCycle) + 
       ( 
       CASE WHEN Datepart(day, @ReportRundDate) > Datepart(day, @billingdate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) * @BillingCycle, @billingdate))-1, 103)
```

But in some cases it generates unexpected results, like when you select month start days like 1, 2, 3 it didn't come up with correct results, but not every month though. I still can't track the exact unexpected result parameters. I will post them as soon as I find out.
Could someone please review this code and let me know if am doing something wrong. In my initial analysis, it seems when I avoid 'CEILING(' it shows correct results in some scenarios and when I use 'CEILING(' the results reverses.

Comment: How do you tell how many days in the future you want to go?

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't understand the question. Could you please take a look at the example scenario in the question.?

Comment: Can you please give some more examples? We need a few different sets of parameters, with your expected results for each parameter set.

Answer (score 0):

It looks on the surface like you just want to add 90 day, not 3 months to the billing start date:

```
DECLARE @ReportRundDate     DATETIME = '20180305', 
        @BillingStartDate   DATETIME = '20180302', 
        @BillingCycle       INT = 3

        SELECT @BillingStartDate, DATEADD(DAY, 30 * @BillingCycle, @ReportRundDate) [NextBillingStartDate];

        SELECT  @ReportRundDate     = '20180605',
                @BillingStartDate   = '20180603';

        SELECT @BillingStartDate, DATEADD(DAY, 30 * @BillingCycle, @ReportRundDate) [NextBillingStartDate];
```

Also, if you avoid using the dashes "-" in your dates, they become locale agnostic. So '2018-02-01' can be the 1st/Feb or the 2nd/Jan depending on the locale of your server, but 20180201 is **always** 1st/Feb/2018.